# Namespace Registries "Link namespace" popup errors out

Tags: managed-package, configuration, developer-edition, dev-hub

Clicking the "Link Namespace" button opens up a new window, but looks to error out almost instantly.

```
error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Looks like it was a mismatch in the Connected App Config. The org domain was changed from its original name... which was still sitting in the config here.